# PHP Yii2 HTTP Client Debugging

Tags: php, http, yii2, httpclient

I am trying to rewrite the following HTTP request using the Yii HTTP Client (under development) exemplified in the docs using the ZEND Http Client:

```
// Create Http client to send the paymentRequest
// We use Zend_Http_Client here, feel free to use your favourite HTTP client library
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($this->donationRequest->getSipsUri());
$client->setParameterPost('Data', $this->donationRequest->toParameterString());
$client->setParameterPost('InterfaceVersion', 'HP_2.3');
$client->setParameterPost('Seal', $this->donationRequest->getShaSign());
$response = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
```

Using Yii, this is what I've come up with:

```
    $client = new Client();
    $data = [
        'Data' => $this->donationRequest->toParameterString(),
        'InterfaceVersion' => 'HP_2.3',
        'Seal' => $this->donationRequest->getShaSign()
    ];
    $client->createRequest()
                    ->setMethod('post')
                    ->setUrl($this->donationRequest->getSipsUri())
                    ->setData($data)->send();
```

When launching this code, I get following error:

```
fopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname
```

How do I properly debug the problem (i.e. see what was submitted and use the result to test through a browser solution)?

Any suggestions to produce similar request as the Zend sample, using the Yii alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) instead which plays nicely with Yii2 and has a simple enough interface. Thanks